How to completly resolve xObjects with the mako core sdk
I have PDF Files as input and some of them do have xObjects. If i just use the IFORMUnpackerTransform the content is not displayed correctly. Is there some better way to do this with mako?
public static IPage explodePageForms(IPage page, IJawsMako mako) {
        try
        {
            IFormUnpackerTransform unpackerTransform = IFormUnpackerTransform.create(mako);
            unpackerTransform.transformPage(page, true, true);
            
            return page;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;

        }
    }

